# jquery loop countdown for every 30 minutes or custom time

Tags: jquery, countdown

I'm trying to have a countdown for every 30 minutes (according to the server time, not client). Every 30 minutes (eg. 10am, 10:30am, 10:30:am [on the tens]) it needs to refresh the page and start over.

I found this url : **[jQuery timer/countdown using server time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282590/jquery-timer-countdown-using-server-time)**

but i don't understand how to change it to my custom time !

Comment: first get server time n convert into `Date` object e.g `var convert_into_date = new Date(parseInt(Date.parse(fetchedtime), 10)).getTime() + 0;` and split it into `currentSec, currentMin` and rest of it will be same

Comment: i changed setupTimer function and now work fine  .  thank you , for example : var baseMins = 0;
    if (currentMin >= 0 && currentMin <= 29)
        baseMins = 30;
    else if (currentMin >= 29 && currentMin <= 59)
        baseMins = 60;